# Android GCM: empty registration id

Tags: android, push-notification

Hi i'm trying to integrate GCM from the [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). I have two package first one is `com.wpeden.social.circle` and second one is `com.wpeden.social.circle.gcm`. In first package i just added my `MainActivity` which call `SignUp` class. I added `google-play-services` and `gcm.jar` in my project. I used all `GCM` requirements `AlertDialogManager,ConnectionDetector,CommonUtilities,ServerUtilities` of the [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) to `com.wpeden.social.circle.gcm`. In my `SignUp` class i used following code to make the device register and save the registration code, name, password to database. But it cann't get registration id and saves only username and password. In my manifest i used following,,

```
<permission android:name="com.wpeden.social.circle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.wpeden.social.circle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<service android:name="com.wpeden.social.circle.gcm.GCMIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.wpeden.social.circle.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In my `SignUp` class

```
wpedenSignUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            userName = wpedenSignUpUserName.getText().toString();
            password = wpedenSignUpPassword.getText().toString();
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(SignUp.this);

            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(SignUp.this);
            registrationId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(SignUp.this);

            if (registrationId.equals("")) {
                GCMRegistrar.register(SignUp.this, SENDER_ID);
            } else {
                if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(SignUp.this)) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this.getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    final Context context = SignUp.this.getApplicationContext();
                    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            ServerUtilities.register(context, userName, password, registrationId);
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            mRegisterTask = null;
                        }

                    };
                    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("this is my reg id:" +registrationId);
            new SignUpUser().execute();
        }
    });

class SignUpUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reg_id", registrationId));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(wpedenSignUpUrl,
                "POST", params);

        String result = "";
        try {
            result = json.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (result.equals(TAG_SUCCESS)) {
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Successfully saved",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            run();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, UserProfileTab.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Failed to save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

It can save username , password but get empty registration id. Thanks in advance

Comment: check logcat any errar is coming

Comment: also check this http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

Comment: No it doesn't show any error

Comment: have u chage the pakage name of app

Comment: @user3384985 :  I think before debugging would like to tell you that Google has changed the approach for getting the Reg id a bit..(a more clear and neat way) which is really an easier way to get. Please have a look https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html Try it and m sure you will get Reg Id in one go for sure

Comment: @MOSO i'm checking it.

Comment: The link you are following is still the old way... just a lil more work bt m sure u'll like the new Google way.. :p